# winerror: The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: python, django

I got this error while running the code from https://github.com/areski/django-audiofield/. I got this error when I tried to save an audio file this error. The exception line 1178 is a startupinfo.

```
FileNotFoundError at /admin/audiofield/audiofile/add/
[WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/audiofield/audiofile/add/
Django Version: 1.11.17
Exception Type: FileNotFoundError
Exception Value:    
[WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
Exception Location: C:\Users\agent\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\subprocess.py in _execute_child, line 1178
Python Executable:  C:\Users\agent\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\python.exe
Python Version: 3.7.2
Python Path:    
['C:\\blogs\\blog\\django_playlist\\djangonautic',
 'C:\\Users\\agent\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37-32\\python37.zip',
 'C:\\Users\\agent\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37-32\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Users\\agent\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37-32\\lib',
 'C:\\Users\\agent\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37-32',
 'C:\\Users\\agent\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37-32\\lib\\site-packages']
Server time:    Sat, 20 Apr 2019 06:13:27 +0000
```

Comment: Can you post the full traceback?

Comment: i already find a way to solve it.. thank you for your response Will Keeling

Comment: by just changing the shell to true